# I cannot update Ruby on Homebrew from 2.0.0 to 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line-interface, ruby-2.3

I am trying to upgrade Ruby because I need to setup a Jekyll template, and I need to latest version to do it. Since I have a Mac running Sierra, I already have Ruby preinstalled as well as the Homebrew installation. When I install it using `brew install ruby`, it works, but when I check the version, it is still at 2.0.0 instead of 2.3.1 where it should be. Homebrew says I have 2.3.1, but the CLI says I have 2.0.0. I tried to use `brew link --override ruby` to make it work, but it said everything was working and it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and plugin [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme). It will keep several versions of ruby on the one machine.

After install go to directory with your code, run `rbenv install 2.3.1` and create file `.ruby-version` containing `2.3.1`. All scripts running from this directory will use ruby 2.3.1.

Or you will able to set ruby version for all running scripts - `rbenv global 2.3.1`